# Output url from a list javascript

Tags: list, javascript, url

I have this code which gets the items from a list and outputs them in an alert, however with urls it inputs [object object]. How can I make it print out the URL or the description

```
var siteUrl = mysite;

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Privacy Statements');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        


function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

var listItemInfo = '';

var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += 
        '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title')
         + 
        '\nPrivacy Statement Urls: ' + oListItem.get_item('PrivacyStatementUrls') ;
}

  alert(listItemInfo.toString());  

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following:

```
alert(myListItem.get_item("HyperLinkFieldName").get_description());
alert(myListItem.get_item("HyperLinkFieldName").get_url());
```